# How to create a new identity in macOS?

Tags: keychain, certificate, macos

I've done likely stupid things in Keychain Access and now I don't have access to identities:

```
user@host:~$ security find-identity

Policy: X.509 Basic
  Matching identities
     0 identities found

  Valid identities only
     0 valid identities found
```

I've imported my certificates from developer.apple.com, but identities are still not shown. I think I'm missing private keys, but I don't know what to do.

I don't seem to have developer IDs in place:

```
user@host:~$ sudo certtool y | grep -i dev
   OrgUnit         : Apple Worldwide Developer Relations
   Common Name     : Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
   Common Name     : iPhone Developer: ...
   OrgUnit         : Apple Worldwide Developer Relations
   Common Name     : Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
   Common Name     : iPhone Developer: ...
```

How can I restore identities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the correct developer identity preferences is done in Xcode.

- Open Xcode
- Select Preferences in the Xcode menu.

[image]

- Click "Accounts"
- If your developer Apple ID is not listed click on the "+" on the left and add it.
- Click on the Apple ID and then "Manage Certificates". This will allow you to create the various required signing certificates.